# WPF Datagrid column count is 0

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
 *string connStr = ConfigValues.connectionString;
 string query = "select * from table";
 using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr))
{
   using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn))
   {
            ds_sc = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds_sc);
   }
}

table_sc = ds_sc.Tables[0];
datagrid.ItemsSource = table_sc.DefaultView;

MessageBox.Show("count=" + dgvScripture.Columns.Count().ToString());

datagrid.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;**
```

This WPF datagrid has 3 columns.
The datagrid column count is zero and im not able to hide the column[1].
I will need to retrieve the column 1 value later in code. 
The error I get is : "Index outside bounds"
Cant find what im missing

Pls help ! Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `AutoGeneratedColumn` then `Columns` are not created immediately after you set `ItemSource`. `DataGrid` has 2 events for this

1) If you want catch moment when **all columns are created** use [`AutoGeneratedColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratedcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) event

> Occurs when auto generation of all columns is completed.
>   ... 
>   The AutoGeneratedColumns event is raised every time the DataGrid attempts to generate columns. For example, AutoGeneratedColumns is raised when the DataGrid is initialized, AutoGenerateColumns is set to true, or the ItemsSource is changed, even if the ItemsSource is null.

2) If you want to do something for each auto generated column **at the moment of its creation** use [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) event

> Occurs when an individual column is auto-generated.
>   ...
>   You can change or cancel the column being created in the AutoGeneratingColumn event handler.

Comment: Thank you so much !! This worked. I hid the columns in the AutoGeneratedColumns event handler.

Comment: I have been trying for the better part of a day to manually set header text and column widths.  Every time the data updated, it would overwrite my definitions.  This allowed me to assign my definitions every time the data is updated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call the LoadingRow event and then hide the views.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).